# Importing an MDX file into a React component to use as text for a tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that utilizes a tooltip and I want to use an MDX file for the text for that tooltip. How would I import the MDX file? It seems like it doesn't import like JSON or TS files. I tried googling but couldn't find an answer. For example:

```
<Component content={content}
```

This would be the component that renders content in a P tag where content is the MDX file.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app or webpack directly?

Comment: create-react-app

Comment: You have the [mdx] tag, but looks like you wanted to tag it as [mdxjs] ? MDX also stands for the Olap querying language - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions

Answer (score 1):

Create-react-app uses a bundler called [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) which is responsible for defining how files that you import are loaded and processed. create-react-app doesn't provide a loader for `.mdx` files and therefore doesn't know how to process it.

To add the loader you probably have to [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) the project so you can tweak the webpack config and add the required loader.

There is a loader available [here](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx).

### Installation

```
npm install --save-dev @mdx-js/loader
```

### Configuration

The loader needs to be used in tandem with the babel-loader. Most projects will typically already include this if you are using JSX syntax.

For webpack projects you can define the following webpack.config.js extension handler for .mdx files:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    // ...

    rules: [
      // ...

      {
        test: /\.mdx$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', '@mdx-js/loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Instructions on how to setup webpack with the loader can also be found [here](https://mdxjs.com/getting-started/webpack).

If you for some reason don't want to eject the project you can also follow [these instructions](https://mdxjs.com/getting-started/create-react-app) which means you will have to inline the loader on every import.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I do not want to eject so I was following the docs with inline importing but keep getting the error ```cannot find module '!babel-loader!@mdx-js/loader!./Content.mdx'``` even though I installed everything the docs told me to . I called my mdx file Content.mdx as well, followed the docs exactly.

Comment: @CaptainFinn Can you share the complete error message please?

Comment: ```Cannot find module '!babel-loader!@mdx-js/loader!./Content.mdx' or it's corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the mdx file like this:
`import Content from "!babel-loader!@mdx js/loader!../../Content.mdx";`

Comment: I can import mdx content with this method but I can't override the element generated from my mdx content using the "components" property. Has someone encountered a similar issue? for reference: https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/ (components section)